# Field Editor 2 broken: Unable to load the requested file: field_row.php

Tags: field-editor

I just purchased and installed **Field Editor 2** on EE 2.10.1 and after going to edit a field group it takes seriously long to load and I get the error:

```
An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested file: field_row.php
```

Is doesn't matter is the field group contains no fields, 2 fields, or 10 fields. It still throughs the error.

I have checks file permissions etc but all OK.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Sounds like it's possible the add-on didn't get installed completely/correctly. I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Strange... I uninstalled it, and re-installed it. Still not working. I deleted all the files and re-uploaded all the files. Still getting the error... annoying!